# Google Map not working in HTML/JS Website

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am confused here because Yesterday everything works fine but today google map is not showing on the website. I haven't change any code and there is php or js error in browser console. Below is the full code:

```
<section class="row map_row">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="contact_section_title">Street Address:</h3>
            <div id="gmap" class="row m0"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

//    google map start
    (function($) {
        "use strict";

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

        var map;

        function init() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(26.201833, 78.159359),
                zoom: 13,
                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
                },
                panControl: true,
                disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                },
                scaleControl: true,
                scrollwheel: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                draggable : true,
                overviewMapControl: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                styles: [ 
//                    { featureType: "administrative", elementType: "all", stylers: [ { visibility: "on" }, { saturation: -100 }, { lightness: 20 } ] },
//                    { featureType: "road", elementType: "all", stylers: [ { visibility: "on" }, { saturation: -100 }, { lightness: 40 } ] },
//                    { featureType: "water", elementType: "all", stylers: [ { visibility: "on" }, { saturation: -10 }, { lightness: 30 } ] },
//                    { featureType: "landscape.man_made", elementType: "all", stylers: [ { visibility: "simplified" }, { saturation: -60 }, { lightness: 10 } ] },
//                    { featureType: "landscape.natural", elementType: "all", stylers: [ { visibility: "simplified" }, { saturation: -60 }, { lightness: 60 } ] },
//                    { featureType: "poi", elementType: "all", stylers: [ { visibility: "off" }, { saturation: -100 }, { lightness: 60 } ] }, 
//                    { featureType: "transit", elementType: "all", stylers: [ { visibility: "off" }, { saturation: -100 }, { lightness: 60 } ] }
                ]

            }

            var mapElement = document.getElementById('gmap');
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

            var locations = [
                ['', 26.201833, 78.159359]
            ];
            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    icon: 'images/map-marker.png',
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                });
            }


    })(jQuery)
//    google map end
```

Kindly help me. I am still learning such stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a lot of errors in it, and it's hard to figure out what exactly is wrong given only this snippet of HTML and Javascript mashed into one.

1. Did you mean to say "there is *no* php or js error in [the] browser console"? If there is an error, we'd like to see it. :)
2. Your JavaScript should be within `<script></script>` tags, or the browser will assume this code is simply text.
3. I put your function into [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) and went through all the syntax errors. I found several things. First, you define `map` near the beginning of your JS with `var map;`, so you don't need to have the `var` keyword after the `init()` function on this line: `var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);`. Second, you shouldn't put a comma after the last element of an array (or if there is only one element in an array), such as in your line `zoomControlOptions: {style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,},`. There were several other places this occurred. Thirdly, in your `for` loop, it isn't necessary to have the keyword `var` within the conditions. So `(i = 0; i < locations.length...` instead of `(var i = 0; i < locations.length...`. Finally, you should never declare a variable within a loop, as you did here:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           icon: 'images/map-marker.png',
           animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
           map: map,
       });
   }
   ```

   That's technically like writing:

   ```
       var marker;
       var marker;
       var marker;
       var marker;
   ```

   Over and over. You should only have one marker variable per scope. I would suggest using an array to store your markers, like this:

   ```
   var markers = [];
   for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
       markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
           icon: 'images/map-marker.png',
           animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
           map: map
       });
   }
   ```

   Here is all of the JavaScript after my edits:

   ```
   function loadMap() {
     "use strict";

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

     function init() {
       var mapOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(26.201833, 78.159359),
         zoom: 13,
         zoomControl: true,
         zoomControlOptions: {
           style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT
         },
         panControl: true,
         disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
         mapTypeControl: false,
         mapTypeControlOptions: {
           style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
         },
         scaleControl: true,
         scrollwheel: false,
         streetViewControl: false,
         draggable: true,
         overviewMapControl: false,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         styles: [{
           featureType: "administrative",
           elementType: "all",
           stylers: [{
             visibility: "on"
           }, {
             saturation: -100
           }, {
             lightness: 20
           }]
         }, {
           featureType: "road",
           elementType: "all",
           stylers: [{
             visibility: "on"
           }, {
             saturation: -100
           }, {
             lightness: 40
           }]
         }, {
           featureType: "water",
           elementType: "all",
           stylers: [{
             visibility: "on"
           }, {
             saturation: -10
           }, {
             lightness: 30
           }]
         }, {
           featureType: "landscape.man_made",
           elementType: "all",
           stylers: [{
             visibility: "simplified"
           }, {
             saturation: -60
           }, {
             lightness: 10
           }]
         }, {
           featureType: "landscape.natural",
           elementType: "all",
           stylers: [{
             visibility: "simplified"
           }, {
             saturation: -60
           }, {
             lightness: 60
           }]
         }, {
           featureType: "poi",
           elementType: "all",
           stylers: [{
             visibility: "off"
           }, {
             saturation: -100
           }, {
             lightness: 60
           }]
         }, {
           featureType: "transit",
           elementType: "all",
           stylers: [{
             visibility: "off"
           }, {
             saturation: -100
           }, {
             lightness: 60
           }]
         }]

       };

       var mapElement = document.getElementById('gmap');
       var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

       var locations = [
         ['', 26.201833, 78.159359]
       ];
       var markers = [];
       for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
         markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
           icon: 'images/map-marker.png',
           animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
           map: map
         }));
       }
     }
   }
     loadMap();
   ```

   I can't guarantee you success if you use this, but at least with the big errors out of the way maybe you can do some debugging.

Comment: Thanks mate for taking the time and provide me the fixed code. I slice up the code and forget to include the PHP include file over footer, this minor mistake headache my whole day. But still thanks for the most advanced way to coding same such code. <!-- Is this website only giving the negative vote for asking such questions? -->

Comment: I don't think the reason for the downvote is the question you asked, but more the way you asked it. We like to see some more info on what you've experienced, what you've already tried to fix it, and evidence that you've done your research on the issue. Asking a question on SO is the last resort - not a first line of defense. Your grammar and formatting of the question is important as well - and if I had to guess, English isn't your first language? There's a lot of grammar mistakes in your question... if you want I could do an edit on it. You're welcome for the help. :)

Comment: Thanks :).. Yeah English is not my primary language and that's why this make confusions. But i am still using grammarly to make something readable :D